# JQuery Check if input is empty and show status of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which I need to check whether it is empty or not:

```
<input id="myinput" name="myinput" type="text" value="hello" />
```

The input above could change any time, so I need to check it on `onchange`?

If my input is not empty then I need to add the class `ok` or else add class `noTxt`.

The class could be added to the element below.

```
<div id="status" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
$('#myinput').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('#status').removeClass('okay').addClass('not-okay');
  } else {
    $('#status').addClass('okay').removeClass('not-okay');
  }
});
```

Comment: this will switch the class on #myinput, not #status

Answer (score 5):

```
var input = $('#myinput');
var status = $('#status');

input.change( function() {
  var empty = ( input.val() == '' );
  status
    .toggleClass('ok', !empty)
    .toggleClass('noTxt', empty);
});
```